# Performing action on gridview cell click in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I want to perform some action by clicking on the grid view cell. i know the row clicking and getting the full row data but i am not able to get the particulate cell event.

[image: screen shot of my gridview]

> as we can see in above grid view, i want to perform action on particulate cell number.

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: i tried to get the cell value in on row data bound event but no luck.

Comment: C#? VB.Net? Which language do you use? Where do you have problems with your code? Where is the piece of code that may not work?

Answer (score 2):

add an on `RowDataBound` like this

```
   protected void Gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gridview, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
       }
    }
```

> you can give cell by its index like this  `e.Row.Cells[1]` for cell 1

you can get any `selected` `row cell` value like this

```
protected void Gridview_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string designation =  Gridview.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    }
```

Comment: thank for reply, but where i can write my code to implement my logic after clicking the cell.

Comment: you can get any value from grid  just add a SelectedIndexChanged event on gridview

Comment: all i want is to get the list of employee on cell click

Comment: ya i can get but how can i perform the action on particular cell,

Comment: i have given my answer as u mention in your question u can still achieve that by this but for that i will suggest you to use link button as a template field that will be more easy way

Comment: check my Updated answer

Comment: thanks for that,but i am new developer so it is little difficult for me.

Comment: on your design add these two event as i mention in my answer and you will achieve that thanks for your future and if it worked for you than mark it as an answer